# Optimizing Calendar Blocks Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization

So this is a tricky one, it's simplified somewhat but is based on a real world problem concerning memory optimization (its not homework)

Say you are a period between two dates, (like 2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31). Now you're given a bunch of  date entries which each contain a date and a color. There's a maximum of one entry per date but all dates might not have an entry.

For example:

2013-01-01  Yellow

2013-01-02  Blue

2013-01-03  Red

2013-01-05  Yellow

[image]

and so forth

Now say we have a span which contains a start date, and enddate, a color. We also have an optional day of week filter, which if declared,can contain one or several days of the week. In those cases the span is only "active" for those days.

For example in the below example we might have:

Span #1: 2013-01-01  -  2013-01-06   BLUE

Span #2: 2013-01-13  -  2013-01-27  RED   Mon

Span #3: 2013-01-08  -  2013-01-26  CYAN Wed Tue Sat Sun

and so forth

The problem is to come up with a feasible algorithm (from performance, memory point of view, and no quant computers :) that comes up with the least amount of spans to describe the given period (doesn't have the be the guaranteed minimum amount however even if that would be nice :) . Spans may overlap.

Brute forcing gets  pretty nasty it would seem but there should be an elegant solution

Comment: By "Spans may overlap" do you mean one cell could belong to different spans of different colors ? (in which case we would need to consider the order of the spans to determine the color of the cell) Or only of the same color (such as "all mondays" and then "06 to 14") ?

Comment: one cell can be "covered" by several spans, but a cell can only ever have one color. The color is just to make it visual, it could be numbers or cells that simply are identical

Answer (score 0):

The problem has some similarities with [circuit minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization) using [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). This problem is known to be NP-hard and therefore algorithms like the [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) have exponential runtime.

Therefore my intention tells my that there is no efficient algorithm for your problem. There are quite a few other covering problems like [vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) and [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) and they are all very hard problems, too. I would try to show that set cover can be reduced to your problem making your problem NP-hard, too.

Comment: I don't know, I thought so too, but I think I actually come up with a pretty efficient algorithm. I'll post in a couple of days if no else cracks it  :)

Comment: Three possibilities: 1) I overestimated the hardness of the problem 2) your algorithm turns out to be not as efficient as you expect (or fails to find the minimum) 3) numberOpenMillenniumPrizeProblems--;

Comment: Haha, probably :) I think there are differences that makes this more solvable though. Maybe I should have said also that the algorithm doesn't have to delived the guarantee minimum amount, only as good as possible

Comment: @DanielBrückner:  konrad's problem is a very special case of a set covering problem.  A whole bunch of covering problems can be solved very efficiently.  When all of the sets are intervals, for example, you can solve set cover in near-linear time.  And that's *almost* the case here; there are just the pesky day-of-week masks upsetting the structure.